# How can I print to the console in color in a cross-platform manner?

Tags: linux, macos, console, colors

How can I output colored text using "printf" on both Mac OS X and Linux?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the ANSI colour codes.  Here's an example program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("%c[1;31mHello, world!\n", 27); // red
  printf("%c[1;32mHello, world!\n", 27); // green
  printf("%c[1;33mHello, world!\n", 27); // yellow
  printf("%c[1;34mHello, world!\n", 27); // blue
  return 0;
}
```

The `27` is the `escape` character.  You can use `\e` if you prefer.

There are lists of all the codes all over the web.  [Here is one](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt).

Comment: Assuming ANSI escape sequences, as popularized by VT100 derivatives (VT1xx didn't have color).  And you could have used `"\033"` instead of `"%c", 27`.

Comment: @ephemient, even `\e` worked on my machine.  OS X's terminal and most linux console apps support the ANSI escape sequences, so I think it satisfies his question.

Comment: If I remember fine, `\e` is gcc-only.

Comment: Any chance you can explain in more detail what is going on here for a newbie? There seems to be nothing in the printf documentation about it. What causes this syntax to work in this way? Just curious to understand it better! Thank you :)

Comment: @Hendeca, that's because it has nothing to do with `printf`.  It's that the terminal program itself interprets these escape codes as commands to change the colour it uses on screen.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is:

```
# Define some colors first (you can put this in your .bashrc file):
red='\e[0;31m'
RED='\e[1;31m'
blue='\e[0;34m'
BLUE='\e[1;34m'
cyan='\e[0;36m'
CYAN='\e[1;36m'
green='\e[0;32m'
GREEN='\e[1;32m'
yellow='\e[0;33m'
YELLOW='\e[1;33m'
NC='\e[0m'
#################
```

Then you can type in the terminal:

```
echo -e "${RED}This is an error${NC}"
echo -e "${YELLOW}This is a warning${NC}"
echo -e "${GREEN}Everythings fine!${NC}"
```

Do not forget the ${NC} at the end. NC stands for "no color", which means that after your sentence, it will revert back to normal color. If you forget it, the whole prompt and commands afterwards will be in the color you specified (of course you can type 'echo -e "${NS}"' to change it back).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in terminal on mac (OS X v10.9.1) - I didn't put it in the .bashrc, just defined it within the shell on the command line - but the text was printed directly.

Comment: The question was about the 'printf' command, not terminal commands. Moreover, a cross platform solution was requested, 'put this in your .bashrc' isn't that.

Comment: @TimZaman Well, technically the OP requested a solution "on both Mac OS X and Linux", so putting it in .bashrc is exactly that. Though i do agree that it isn't answering how to do it using "printf". I do feel the need to point out that i gave my answer as an alternative: "Another option is:", rather than stating this actually was the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the best portability, query the [terminfo](http://catb.org/terminfo/) database.  In shell,

```
colors=(black red green yellow blue magenta cyan white)
for ((i = 0; i < ${#colors[*]}; i++)); do
    ((j=(i+1)%${#colors[*]}))
    printf '%s%s%s on %s%s\n' "$(tput setaf $i)" "$(tput setab $j)" \
            "${colors[i]}" "${colors[j]}" "$(tput op)"
done
```

will print out

```
black on red
red on green
green on yellow
yellow on blue
blue on magenta
magenta on cyan
cyan on white
white on black
```

but in color.

Comment: +1 nice, but how do I do this from C?  I can't seem to find library equivalents for tput - maybe yank it directly from open source?