# User string input show in color

Tags: c

I am using a Solaris server in my engineering course. Running code through SecureCRT and the gcc compiler. A task we have is to have the user input a string, and for the program to reverse it. The input string needs to show up in red, and I do not know what code manipulates colors to screen.

See  Image for input /output
[image: The image of the input/output style]

I tried running the code from the first link below, and it didnt output in any colors. It still shows all of the words in the standard black and white

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585846/color-text-in-terminal-aplications-in-unix

Comment: Look to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274824/color-console-in-ansi-c), hope it's helpful

Comment: you should be able to write the appropriate control characters to stdout to change color (then again to change it back) \\033[1;31m is red \\033[1;39m is white

Answer (score 3):

Look into [**ncurses**](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).  It's a library built to handle this sort of thing, among other formatting.

[**start_color()**](http://man.he.net/man3/start_color) in `curses` might be a good start.