# how to change colour of a specific output on console in c++

Tags: c++, windows

//following codes once change the colour, then they keep them along all the way, //if i want to write juxt one word with different colour like cout<<"4June" //should be with red jxt the colour of text should change not the background //colour and the if i display something like cout<<"colour not changed"; then //colour should be the original one, how to attain that c++????

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   HANDLE consolehwnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
   cout << "this text is not colorized\n";
   SetConsoleTextAttribute(consolehwnd, FOREGROUND_RED);
   cout << "this text shows as red\n";
   SetConsoleTextAttribute(consolehwnd, FOREGROUND_BLUE);
   cout << "this text shows as blue\n";
}


OR

SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),1)

OR

system("color 3");
cout<<"colour changed"<<endl;**
```

Comment: Windows? Linux? OS X? Platform independent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using C/C++, how do you print to stdout in color, but only if the terminal supports it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827143/using-c-c-how-do-you-print-to-stdout-in-color-but-only-if-the-terminal-suppo)

Comment: I dont know much, m using visual studio 2012

Comment: I use Curses. If you build a wrapper class for it (it's c code), it's fairly straightforward to use.

Comment: i want c++ code, and i got all these codes from website infact from a question posted here, but these codes once change the colour they keep on, i dnt know how to reset, i jxt want a word to be different colour and remaining to be of same orignal colour which is by default console output colour

Answer (score 4):

if you want `red` text to a `black` background you would just type   `SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),4); cout<<"4th June";`

To reset back to normal color, set it to color `7`. `SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),7);`

[image]

Here is a table of all the Console colors. you can make 256 combinations by just entering the color code number from the above image to get the desired color.

Below is some console color management code.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;




void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void setcolor(WORD color);
void setForeGroundAndBackGroundColor(int ForeGroundColor,int BackGroundColor);
void clrscr(); 
void printAllColors();



int main()
{
  // set red text on black background    
  gotoxy(30,10);
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),4); cout<<"4th June";  

  // set white text on black background
  gotoxy(1,23);
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),7);



  return 0;
}


void setcolor(WORD color)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),color);
    return;
}



void setForeGroundAndBackGroundColor(int ForeGroundColor,int BackGroundColor)
{
   int color=16*BackGroundColor+ForeGroundColor;
   setcolor(color);
}




void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
    return;
}




void clrscr()
{
    COORD coordScreen = { 0, 0 };
    DWORD cCharsWritten;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    DWORD dwConSize;
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
    dwConSize = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, TEXT(' '), dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hConsole, csbi.wAttributes, dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coordScreen);
    return;
}


void printAllColors()
{
   int ix=0;
   int iy=1;
   int col=0;
   setcolor(7);
   clrscr();

   // Demo setForeGroundAndBackGroundColor
   for (int i =0;i<16;i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<16;j++)
      {
       setForeGroundAndBackGroundColor(i,j);
       gotoxy(i*5  , iy+j); cout<<""<<i + (16 *j)<<"";
       col++;
      }
   }


   setcolor(31);
   cout<<"\n";

  gotoxy(1,23);
}


/*

Color      Background    Foreground
---------------------------------------------
Black            0           0
Blue             1           1
Green            2           2
Cyan             3           3
Red              4           4
Magenta          5           5
Brown            6           6
White            7           7
Gray             -           8
Intense Blue     -           9
Intense Green    -           10
Intense Cyan     -           11
Intense Red      -           12
Intense Magenta  -           13
Yellow           -           14
Intense White    -           15



  */
```